# Upgrade AngularJS ServiceProvider which provides an interface

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade AngularJS service provider (TranslateProvider) which return an instance of an interface from it's `$get` function.

The problem is that in the Angular provider object (translateProvider) the `provide` field should be `Translate` but it cannot be used because TypeScript interfaces are for compile-time only. This is the error I get:

```
TS2693: 'Translate' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

This is the gist of the source code:

```
export class TranslateProvider implements ng.IServiceProvider {

    public $get() {

        const service: Translate = <Translate> function translate(key: string, parameters: Dictionary<StringLike>): string {

        return service;
    }
}

export interface Translate {
    (translationKey: string, parameters?: Dictionary<StringLike>): string;
}

export function translateFactory(i: any) {
    return i.get('translate');
}

export const translateProvider = {
    provide: TranslateProvider,
    useFactory: translateFactory,
    deps: ['$injector']
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
    ],
    providers: [
        translateProvider,
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found in [Angular docs the explanation about Injection Tokens](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens).

Somewhere in the code (usually in the file where the interface is defined) you need to add

`export const TRANSLATE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Translate>('Translate');`

This token can be used later to ask the injector for this service.

The upgrade registration now looks like this:

```
export const translateProvider = {
    provide: TRANSLATE_TOKEN,
    useFactory: translateFactory,
    deps: ['$injector']
};
```

And finally the ctor of the component that will use this dependency looks like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATE_TOKEN) private translate: Translate) {
}
```